# Implementing IWorkbenchPreferencePage gives NPE when viewing preference page

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a Eclipse RCP (3.6) plugin that needs some preference pages. At the moment I can't even get one working. I've googled for tutorials, but they all use a different version of IWorkbenchPreferencePage (it seems).

This is the stack trace: http://codepad.org/tu2WTwAA , which has the following first exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1282)
```

The following is my plugin.xml entry, which shouldn't matter since the Node is in the preferences view.

```
<extension
      point = "org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages">
      <page id="com.test.menuplugin.preferences.general"
           class="com.gdeb.menuplugin.preferences.GeneralPreferences"
           name="Helpers">
      </page>
</extension>
```

Following this is my **GeneralPreferences** class: http://dpaste.com/hold/778180/

I went through the API ( [IWorkbenchPreferencePage@Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPreferencePage.html) ) and still have no clue. I even tried to look at Vogelles tutorial but that was too different from the interface provided.

What am I doing wrong, should I be implementing some kind of preference objects like PreferenceDialog (seems like that's if you want preferences independent of the global preferences)?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that was a wrong answer.

In Eclipse 3.7 NPE on that line might be caused by a `null` returned from your `computeSize` function (and it most definitely looks like your class field `size` may be `null` at that point). See `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.computeSize()` for how platform computes the size.

Comment: There is no `setControl()` method. Did you mean `setContainer()`? Furthermore, once I created that method `private void setControl( Composite parent ) { this.parent = ( Composite ) parent; }` I still get the same error.

Comment: I apologize for bogus answer, I just assumed it's a problem I often hit. I updated my answer after actually looking at your code :)